# JodaTime: Datetime with +00:00 instead Z

Tags: java, jodatime

Hello I have a problem with joda time. My application speaks with a remote service and this service have problems with this string:

```
2015-04-14T09:29:02.485Z
```

So I tested it with the same (see Z):

```
2015-04-14T09:29:02.485+00:00
```

and this works. So how can I easily remove the Z and use 00:00, what is exactly the same? I dont want to write my own formatter, because it have to be iso 8601. Is there an easy way to do this?

I have the following code:

```
...
public void myMethod(Datetime time){
    remoteCall(time.toString);
}
...
```

Comment: Just FYI: `Z` is perfectly fine for ISO8601

Comment: Both are ISO8601, if you use JSR-310 (built in to Java 8 and back ported to Java 7) you can control this time zone format easily.

Comment: I know both are valid, but remote service has some bugs with Z at the end, so I want to try a workaround with +00:00.

Comment: Why do you not want to use [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendTimeZoneOffset(java.lang.String, boolean, int, int))? You can use it to define your variant of ISO-8601 (remember that there is not only one format specified). Or you just use `String.replace(...)`.

Comment: I want to use iso8601, but I thought there is some 'setZeroInsteadZ(true)' method. In the end the requirement is, that the application is fully iso8601 compatible. And thats not the case if I use my custom format, especially if we change the remote service or remote will be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace Z with +00:00, you may try this, I reused your code above:

```
    public void myMethod(Datetime time){
    /**
     * this will return in this format 2015-04-14T09:29:02.485+00:00
     * assumption is that time in UTC Timezone
     */
    remoteCall(time.toString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ"));
}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Joda-Time, we can achieve this. Below small program can help you

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;    
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;    
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;    
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class TestTimezone {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DateTime jodatime = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOut = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSSZZ");
        System.out.println(dtfOut.print(jodatime));

    }

}
```